# JDBC: is there are away to get a size of committed data in bytes

Tags: java, jdbc

If I have a java application that performs some inserts against a database, if there an easy  way to get how much bytes was committed (i.e. sum size of all the data in all the fields), without having to calculate it manually / fetching and checking the size of the result set?

--

As `lucho` points out, implementing statistics-aware statement class on top of the PreparedStatement might be the way to go. Going to stick with that and see how well this is going to work.

Comment: Not that I know of.  Never heard of it; not sure why it'd be important.  Would you be trying to anticipate filling up a disk before it happened?

Comment: I am trying to get an approximation of how much data is committed to the database per second to the user.

Comment: Given the cost of a 2TB today, buying more disk might be simpler.

Comment: @Nikita, Why would the user care? How important is that this number be accurate?  What would the user do if this number was higher or lower than they expected?

Comment: BTW: The size of the data you send and the amount of space it takes on disk are not the same.  Which is of more interest? i.e. the sum of the size of the fields will not match how much space is used.

Comment: @Peter, fair enough, I am interested in the amount of data I am pushing into the database, not the amount of space it will use to store it.

Comment: Also, not user won't be able to do anything to do that. She doesn't need to do anything about it either, just seems to be like a better representation of the rate than insert statements in second.

Comment: @Nikita - the amount of data that you push to the database is a different measure again.  I agree that this is of little or no interest to a normal user.  What *is* interesting is an estimate of how much time until the request finishes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, nope.

You'll have to ask your database that question; perhaps it's possible to do it without querying the same thing you inserted (because that sounds a bit pointless).

Comment: Yeah, it sounds pointless to me too ;) The database will give me the answer, but not in real time (e.g. I can run stats commands and check results, but the overhead of doing that after every single batch is huge).

Comment: Then perhaps you can implement your own JDBC statement, add the stats functionality and delegate the rest to the driver's implementation. We have used this approach for performance monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I like lucho's solution, but I have two quicker (hackier) options:

1. You can try to use InnoDB's SHOW TABLE STATUS and keep a running log of the data size. That would let you know, but on my development machine calling it on one database takes 5.3s (56 tables) so unless you only want the data for one or two tables it's probably too slow (not to mention whatever locking it may incur).
2. You could monitor the DB process and use the OS to tell you how much it's writing. I know Windows can tell you this, and I'm pretty sure Linux can as well. But if you host 3 databases you'll only get the total, and it will be off some due to transactions and such.

Just random ideas.